# Combining text values together using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a XML file. Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<AssignmentHistory>
<W20160104>
    <StudentItems>
        <Item>
            <Name Counsel="13">Name 1</Name>
            <Type>Type 1</Type>
        </Item>
    </StudentItems>
</W20160104>
```

I am wanting to create a XSL script that  primarily works with another XML file. However, it also refers to the above external XML file using this method:

```
<xsl:variable name="MyXML" select "document('history.xml')"/>
```

In  the main XML file, I am in a 'Meeting' node which has this content:

```
<MeetingDate Day="7" DayShort="Thu" DayFull="Thursday" Month="1" MonthShort="Jan" MonthFull="January" Year="2016"/>
```

What I want to do, is combine the @Day, @Month and @Year attributes so that I end up with "WYYYYMMDD" so that I can then hopefully locate:

```
/AssignmentHistory/WYYYYMMDD
```

So that I can then include some values from that node in MyXML in my final output.

Can you please advise me how to take the attributes and convert them into "WYYYYMMDD"?

Thank you very much.

Thanks to your comments I made some progress. I can now format the WYYYYMMDD text value. But I am struggling to iterate the external document:

```
            <xsl:variable name="AssignHistory" select="document('AssignHistory.xml')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="y" select="MeetingDate/@Year"/>
            <xsl:variable name="m" select="format-number(MeetingDate/@Month, '00')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="d" select="format-number(MeetingDate/@Day, '00')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="week" select="concat('W',$y,$m,$d)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$week"/><br />
            <xsl:for-each select="$AssignHistory/AssignmentHistory/*[name()=$week]/StudentItems/Item">
              Student (or assistant): <xsl:value-of select="Name"/><br />
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Nothing is showing.

Comment: Please post a minimal, but **complete** example, so we can see the context. -- The one thing that stands out is that `Name` is not a child of the current node. You probably want `xsl:value-of select=".//Name"/>` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way to produce string in the desired format `"WYYYMMDD"` :

```
<xsl:template match="MeetingDate">
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="@Year"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="format-number(@Month, '00')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="format-number(@Day, '00')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="concat('W',$y,$m,$d)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltranfsorm.net demo`](http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9F/1)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
W20160107
```

`xsl:variable`s are used above to split the expression into chunks to make it easier to read. The actual usage for selecting target element from the XML document variable should look about like this :

```
<xsl:value-of select="$MyXML/AssignmentHistory/*[name()=$name]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @har07. I have three questions: 1.How can I store the result into a variable so I can just use the variable rather than prefix all my select calls with the long concat one? 2. It is possible to add 7 days onto the date so that I can use a date one week in the future? 3. How do I know if the node was not found? Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I suggest you make #2 a separate question.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle 1. updated the answer to address this 2. that's another topic, better post a separate question as suggested by michael 3. `xsl:value-of` doesn't return value? (I don't fully understand this question)

Comment: @har07, thanks. I am struggling to use this value to iterate the node contents in the external file. Please see updated issue above. Thanks.

Comment: Sussed it, my fault. Thanks! Sorted.